# How to extract a gzip file and read its contents in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, hadoop, gzip

I have a lot of gzip files which I need to extract. The file name looks like this -
FGT6HD3917800515[root].2020-07-03-13-20-35.tlog.1593759574.csv

All these files have a single CSV file each. I want to read the contents of these CSV files in a dataframe in Python. The data in CSV looks like this -

NTP 1593759574  accept  unscanned       India   port10  1x.1xx.xx.xxx   123 1593779419  181                         17  India   portxx  1xx.xxx.1xx.1xx         42338   1xx.1xx.xxx.xx  123 1xx.1xx.xxx.x   42338

This is what I have tried -

```
import gzip
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

list = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\SAKSHI SHARMA\.spyder-py3\filter data\')
print(list);

a = np.empty((0))

for i in list:
    with gzip.open(r'C:\Users\SAKSHI SHARMA\.spyder-py3\filter data/'+i) as f:  #why do I have to give /
        features_train = pd.read_csv(f)
        a = np.append(a,features_train)
        del features_train
final_data = pd.concat(a, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(final_data)
```

I get the following error `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

I was suggested by someone to incorporate Hadoop as I am working on ~40 GB of data. However, I have a lot to learn and work on in Python and switching to a new software like Hadoop would make things complicated for me.
Can someone please help me out on how to read these types of zipped files and read the contents on in a dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check Dask Library as following, which reads many files to one df

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> df = dd.read_csv('data*.csv')
```

Read their docs https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Read-CSV-files

Comment: This step will be useful after I extract the CSV files.